# Trouble with data not saving with bindings and shared NSUserDefaults in IB

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings, nsuserdefaults

I'm having a bit of a strange issue that I can't quite figure out. I'm somewhat of a n00b to Interface Builder. What I am trying to do seems like it should be simple, but it's not working for some reason.

In interface builder I have a preferences window with a simple NSTextField. I have set the value binding to the Shared User Defaults Controller with the controller key "values" and model key "test". I build/run my app and open the preferences window, type some random value into said text field, close the window. Command-Q the app. Then in a shell i do a "defaults read com.xxx.yyy" for my app and the key and value are nowhere to be found. That being said, it seems like the next time I fire up the app and change the value it works but only if I switch focus off of the NSTextField before closing the window.

In the documentation for NSUserDefaults it says that the shared controller saves values immediately, am I missing something stupid here?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm answering this a long time after it was asked in case others find it useful.

It sounds like you need to set "Continuously Updates Values" for the text field you've bound. Otherwise, the value is only sent and, accordingly, the preferences only updated when something happens to 'finalise' the edit. That's usually triggered by pressing Return and probably also happens when you switch focus away from the window (though I just tested this in one of my own applications and it didn't seem to commit the edit).